# Why this JS code writting to a hole file so slow on Windows?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, windows

```js
var
fs = require('fs'),
target = 'test',
size = 2 * 1024 ** 3,
content = Buffer.from('TEST'),

fd = fs.openSync(target,'w');

console.time('Truncate')
fs.ftruncateSync(fd,size)
console.timeEnd('Truncate')
fs.closeSync(fd)

console.log(fs.statSync(target).size)
fd = fs.openSync(target,'r+')

console.time('Write to 1GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size / 2)
console.timeEnd('Write to 1GB position')

console.time('Write to 0.5GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size / 4)
console.timeEnd('Write to 0.5GB position')

console.time('Write to 2GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size - 100)
console.timeEnd('Write to 2GB position')

console.time('Write to 1GB position again')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,100 + size / 2)
console.timeEnd('Write to 1GB position again')

console.time('Write to 2GB position again')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size - content.length)
console.timeEnd('Write to 2GB position again')

fs.closeSync(fd)
```

Output from a x86_64 Windows 10

```
Truncate: 4.559ms
2147483648
Write to 1GB position: 5195.480ms
Write to 0.5GB position: 0.096ms
Write to 2GB position: 6506.196ms
Write to 1GB position again: 0.032ms
Write to 2GB position again: 0.023ms
```

And on Ubuntu 16.04 in a virtual machine running on the Windows above

```
Truncate: 0.380ms
2147483648
Write to 1GB position: 0.311ms
Write to 0.5GB position: 0.021ms
Write to 2GB position: 0.330ms
Write to 1GB position again: 0.010ms
Write to 2GB position again: 0.011ms
```

Both using the latest node executable

The results are the same even if I remove the `truncate` part, which is what I thought the cause of slow

Please help me improve it
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you disabled write caching on the disk in Windows 10?

Comment: @ChatterOne 'Enable write caching...' is checked for all disks as default

Comment: That is interesting, because you see that the second time you write to the file, it's almost as fast as the Linux equivalent (a bit slower, but nothing terrible). So, that would suggest something to do with caching. I don't have a Windows PC ready, maybe I'll try later, but on Mac OS it's not slow.

Comment: It might be possible that Linux (or a part of the stack below your code and the OS) optimizes things by making the file a sparse file, while Windows doesn't?

Comment: You should also try whether different file systems on the Linux box have different performance characteristics here.